# Should I care when a dupe question gets marked as a dupe of the wrong question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If I should, what more should I be doing then I've done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555939/what-is-fact-i)?

Aside from adding comments and editing the question to make it clearer, I did flag it.  Been hours and nothings happening.

Comment: Note: I've re-opened the question.

Comment: No, not much you can do about it.  SE just got 40 million bucks thrown at them by rich men that like this kind of Q+A a lot.  Basic bottom-line, professionals are entirely too expensive and getting volunteers work for free to assist the cheap labor entirely too attractive.  If that is not what you meant, I'm guessing, then you could just create your own Q+A pairs to cover the other assignment operators as well.  Just post one each, start with, say, /=, &=, |=, ^=.  Not sure if you need to cover +=, -=, they usually get those.  Enjoy.

Comment: @HansPassant I know it's late, but I've read your comment 3 times now and the most intelligent response I can make to it is: Huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be startled at hours passing and nothing happening, it can take a day or so for mods to get to your flag. While it's important enough, it's not *urgent* in the sense of 'horrible stuff is on the site and needs obliterated ASAP', or 'this person is chasing away all the new users because he's mean'. You flagged just 2 hours ago, and there aren't a lot of mods active until at least 4 hours from now.

Duplicates should *always* be ordered by technical merit and no other factor. Two things can go wrong when they're marked as such:

- The question *wasn't* a duplicate at all, but an entirely different question
- The question *was* a dupe, but is definitely better than the suggested duplicate

In the first case, you can (as you have) flag and just wait for the mods to check it out. You can also bring it up here on meta - just start a new [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and title it something like "Was question 12345 incorrectly identified as a duplicate?" - in fact the second can sometimes be faster and better all around. But, please - ***edit the question*** (as you did) so it's much clearer that it's not a duplicate.

In the second case, we should always favor the *best* question / answer pair out of the bunch as being the canonical. It doesn't matter which one is older, it just matters which one is the most likely to be of the most use to folks. You almost always need to flag and be patient for these, as there's also the possibility of a merge needing to happen if the answers fit equally well under any of the questions.

Answer (score -4):

yeah of course for the sake of that person and of the others..